# How can i stop and start a logic app on azure using powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to stop and start ie restart a logic app on Azure using Powershell

I have looked at the documentation and it shows the following:

```
Stop-AzureRmLogicAppRun -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name 
"LogicApp03" -RunName "08587489104702792076" -Force
```

But where can i find the -RunName on Azure ?

Answer (score 1):

Runs appears in the `Runs history`:

[image]

The `RunName` is just the run identifier.

So you can get it from azure portal or you can get runs history using powershell with `Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory` (or `Get-AzLogicAppRunHistory` if you're using the new [az powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.6.0)).

To get all the `Running` runs, you can try this command:

`Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory -ResourceGroupName <rg name> -Name <logicapp name> | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}`

Also if you want to disable a logic app, you use this command:

`Set-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName <rg name> -Name <logicapp name> -State "Disabled"`

Comment: Can this be used to also set the Status of the Logic app to disabled / enabled ?

Comment: You can use the `Set-AzureRmLogicApp` and change the state to disabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.logicapp/set-azurermlogicapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: I have looked at this , cant seem to find the -DefinitionFilePath  or -ParameterFilePath . Can I use without these setting these parameters?

Comment: @Mel, updated my answer with the Set-AzureRmLogicApp command. If you can accept the answer it will be great.